# display the total input rounded up

Tags: jquery

thank you in advance for your help.
I was wondering how can I do to display the total rounded up in case of odd number.
Thanks
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.variable-field').on("input", function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var qty = $row.find('.quantity').val() || 0;
    $row.find('.totalcostprice').val(qty / 3);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered proposal-table" id="proposal-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control variable-field quantity" name="Quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control width-80 totalcostprice" name="TotalCostPrice" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for but the [Math.ceil()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp#:~:text=JavaScript%20Math.ceil()&text=The%20Math.ceil()%20method,UP%20to%20the%20nearest%20integer.) method does the job to round UP a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil). Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.variable-field').on("input", function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var qty = $row.find('.quantity').val() || 0;
    $row.find('.totalcostprice').val(Math.ceil(qty / 3));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered proposal-table" id="proposal-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control variable-field quantity" name="Quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control width-80 totalcostprice" name="TotalCostPrice" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```